# How to get in a script a variable was set in console

Tags: linux, bash, console, sh

I want to pass a variable was set in console to the script. Using argument is deprecated in this case. The "decision in a forehead" doesn't work:

```
$ echo 'echo $VAR' > script.sh
$ cat ./script.sh
echo $VAR
$ ./script.sh

$ VAR=1
$ ./script.sh

$
```

But I expect result `1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to "export" that variable so that it is inherited by spawned processes:

```
$ echo 'echo $VAR' > script.sh
$ cat ./script.sh
echo $VAR
$ chmod a+x ./script.sh
$ ./script.sh

$ VAR='hello world'
$ export VAR
$ ./script.sh
hello world
$
```

---

```
$ VAR='hello world'
$ export VAR
```

can be shortened in bash:

```
export VAR='hello world'
```